# Error during passing data from parent to child component with input binding

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass data from parent component to child component using input binding. It is a simple boolean field. I followed this Angular [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding) to accomplish it but I am still not able to get anything from parent to child component.

Also I dont know if its worth mentioning, at first I was getting the below error then I added schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA] in my app module and it went away. 
[image]

Below is my parent component.ts code for the variable I want to pass:

```
 public isAnAuthorizedUser: boolean = true;

   ngOnInit(): void {

        if (test != null) {
            console.log("Inside NGOnInit on page 1");
            this.route.params
                .switchMap((params: Params) => this._Service.getRequestById(+params['id']))
                .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.Model = data;
                    if (this.Model.isAuthorizedToView != true)
                    {
                        this.isAnAuthorizedUser = false;
                        this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                    }
        }
```

Here is my parent component html that I am trying to pass.

```
 <div>
                <isAnAuthorizedUser [data]="isAnAuthorizedUser"></isAnAuthorizedUser>
            </div>
```

Below is my child component TS file code:

```
   import { Component, OnInit, Input, Injectable, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core'
import {
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormGroup,
    FormControl
} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'ReservationFormPage1',
    templateUrl: './ReqDashboard.html'
    ,
    providers: [ReqFormService, CompleteRequestService, IncompleteRequestService]
})

export class ReservationDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    isAnAuthorizedUser: boolean;
                ngOnInit(): void {
                    console.log(this.isAnAuthorizedUser);
    }

}
```

Below is the HTML code where I am testing to access my pass in varianble:

```
 <div *ngIf ="isAnAuthorizedUser">
        <span>{{this.isAnAuthorizedUser}}</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where does this `<isAnAuthorizedUser>` element come from ?

Comment: @n00dl3 so what are you suggesting. please explain

Comment: I just added <isAnAuthorizedUser> element in html without adding anywhere @n00dl3

Comment: What do you expect from this element ? Is it a declared component ?

Comment: I don't see any reference to a component declared with `isAnAuthorizedUser` as selector, that's why I'm asking...

Answer (score 0):

the property name in html should match the name of your @Input property name.

try below,

```
<isAnAuthorizedUser [isAnAuthorizedUser]="isAnAuthorizedUser"></isAnAuthorizedUser>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do in your component:

```
@Input('data') isAnAuthorizedUser;
```

and then in your template

```
<isAnAuthorizedUser [isAnAuthorizedUser]="true"></isAnAuthorizedUser>
```